CORS error on Heroku API from Apple Testflight
I'm using Python back-end and React Native on front-end.
I deployed my backend on Heroku and setted up my enviroment correctly, when I start the server, the API calls works perfectly, but, when I use my Testflight from Apple connect, I get the error below.

Fail fetch please try again later"

My init:
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import openai
from Backend.config import Config

def create_app():
    app =  Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config) 
    
    CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
    openai.api_key = Config.OPENAI_API_KEY
    app.secret_key = Config.SECRET_KEY 
       
    from .main.route import main

    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app

React Native:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { GPT_URL } from '@env';

const GPTApiCall = ({ inputText }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('API URL:', GPT_URL); // Verify the URL
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${GPT_URL}/generaterecipe`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ input_text: inputText }),
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        const data = await response.json();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        Alert.alert('Error', `Failed to fetch data: ${error.message}`);
      } finally {
        setIsLoading(false);
      }
    };

    if (inputText) {
      fetchData();
    }
  }, [inputText]);

  return (
    <View>
      {isLoading ? <Text>Loading...</Text> : <Text>{JSON.stringify(data)}</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};

export default GPTApiCall;

     import os
     from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
     
     
     load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
     
     
     class Config:
         SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
         OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')
         CORS_RESOURCES = os.getenv('CORS_RESOURCES')
         port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))
         CORS_RESOURCES = '{r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}'

does anyonme knows what my issue could be? I have been stuck on this for months.
Thank you in advance
I have tried editing the CORS and follow all the intructions to fix this conection, I just feel I am doing somethign wrong. I expect to receive the API CALL back on TEST FLIGHT
